# ScrollBox прокрутка изображения

Tags: delphi, прокрутка, изображения

Здравствуйте. Рисую на компоненте Image определенную фигуру, необходимо добавить возможность сколлинга нарисованной фигуры. Добавил на форму ScrollBox, в него пихнул Image ([вот так](http://gyazo.com/8b79c28d54e11140354fed14a0c1b5bf)), но изображение так и не скроллится, потыка в настройки, но это не дало результата. Как мне можно добавить сколл ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Для начала вам надо сделать размер TImage таким, какой у вашей картинки. И тогда, если  TImage будет заходить за границы TScrollBox, в TScrollBox появятся ползунки, и вы нормально сможете скроллить изображение.

Comment: ну я так и сделал, все равно ничего не происходит (( может я что то не то делаю

Comment: у TImage включено свойство AutoSize?  
у скроллбаров компонента TScrollBox включено свойство Visible?

Comment: AutoSize true, visible true

Answer (score 1):

Видимо, размер самого компонента Image не превышает размер ScrollBox'а...
попробуйте программно увеличить размер Image. 
    Image1.width := ...; Image1.height := ...

Comment: ничего не дало ((

Comment: У меня все "дало".
Если размеры содержимого превышают размеры скроллбокса, то появляются ползунки...

Answer (score 0):

Image1.align -> alnone  и скролы появились